# How do I correctly append a user certificate from a .pfx file to a soap request when communicating with a thiry party service?

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, certificate

I'm using C# to do this. I'm using a third party API to communicate with a service via SOAP requests, and they want me to append a client certificate from a .pfx file they gave me to each SOAP request I send to them.

```
var serv = new MonetaSoapService.PublicSoapClient();
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2("certificate.pfx","password", X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
serv.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = cert;
LogInWs f = serv.LogIn(""); // LogIn is an operation on the server, it returns a LogInWs object, which contains info of the success or failure of the log in operation.
Console.WriteLine(f.ErrorDescription);
```

This will then give an

> "Unknown certificate error"

sent back from the server.

I also saw that the `.pfx` file actually contains 3 certificates (root, intermediate and client), by importing it in a collection. Upon sending only the client certificate, it says that it's unknown but when I try to send either of the remaining ones, it says that anonymous connections are not allowed, So, I guess the servers act as if the certificate is not there in the first place. Should I somehow have to send all three as a chain?

Comment: Your code is incomplete or confusing. What is `serv` variable? `LogInWs` is it your service? Don't you added the certificate to your service? Something like `f.ClientCertificates.Add(cert)`?

Comment: thanks, I've updated it a bit, it should be much clearer now.

Comment: The error happens in line `LogInWs f = serv.LogIn("");` ?

Comment: Console.WriteLine(f.ErrorDescription) prints "Unknown certificate error" to the console

Comment: Have you tried adding certificate to proxy, doing `f.ClientCertificates.Add(cert)` ?

Comment: there is no such method available for f

Answer (score 1):

In my case I first install certificate and then use code like this and I'm able to get response.

```
oClient = new YourClientObject();
oClient.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "Certificate Name");
oClient.Open();
```

Comment: could you elaborate on 'installing'?

Comment: You can use this link https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/pfx-import-export-iis-7.htm @KristijanMirčeta